# How to set and check a session after login?

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm new to PHP and struggling with a login page.  I have the following script that "works" but now I'd like to set a session if the user's password is correct that I can carry over to other pages.  So I'm trying to figure out what needs to be on those other pages to check for the session.

From this, if I put something like this on the page I'm coming back to:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['login'] = "1") {  
echo "you are logged in";
}
else
{
echo "you are not logged in";
}
?>
```

It seems like I get my success message all the time.  I must not be understanding how this works.  Any suggestions appreciated--am up for totally rewriting this if I need to.  Thanks!

Here's my current login script:

```
<?php
// error reporting
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host="foo"; // Host name
$username="foo"; // Mysql username
$password="foo"; // Mysql password
$db_name="foo"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
header ("Location: http://www.google.com");
}
else {  
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = '';
header ("Location: http://www.yahoo.com");
}
?>
```

Applying changes suggested below, I have the following in the page I'm coming back to:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['login'] == "1") {  
echo "you are logged in";
}
else if ($_SESSION['login'] == "") 
{
echo "you are not logged in";
}
?>
```

and the following change to my login script:

```
if($count==1) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] =="1";
header ("Location: login.php");
}
else {  
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] == "";
header ("Location: login.php");
}
```

Now no matter what, I'm getting my "you are not signed in" message...hmm.

Update--OK--if I DON'T make the == change to my script it seems to work.  If I have

```
if($count==1) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
header ("Location: login.php");
}
else {  
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "";
header ("Location: login.php");
}
```

and this in the page I come back to:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['login'] == "1") {  
echo "you are logged in";
}
else if ($_SESSION['login'] == "") 
{
echo "you are not logged in";
?>
```

...that seems to work.

Comment: You must also call `session_start()` on the other page that accesses `$_SESSION`.  All scripts that access `$_SESSION` need a `session_start()`

Comment: There is an error `$_SESSION['login'] = "1"` must be `$_SESSION['login'] == "1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:  if ($_SESSION['login'] == "1")

because the way you are doing it, it sets the value and returns true.

Comment: even more secure is to use if ($_SESSION['login'] === "1") because === checks for the type as well

For example:

$integer === 4 (true)
$integer === "test" (false)
$integer === "4" (false)
$string === "test" (true)
$string === "4" (true)
$string === 4 (false)

Comment: I attempted to add the edits recommended--now I seem to get my "you are not signed in" echo every time.  See any additional issues with my code?

Comment: Edit: made the changes above, and SEEM to be OK now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your varible $myusername and $mypassword has been specified for two different functions, you surpose to indivisualise them.......