# Cant login after SESSION check

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have the website pages for visitors and the pages for the client manage it on /admin

I created a login system at admin/index.php and it's working fine. But, if I type the url of an admin page in the browser (e.g admin/carro_admin.php) I get access even without been loged. So I'm trying to put some session check on this page (carro_admin) to block visitors and allow just login access.

I trying to do that with:

```
if (isset($_SESSION)) {
  header("location:carro_admin.php");   
}

else {
    header("location:index.php");   
}

exit();
```

It's blocking the access and sending me to index.php (and that's right). But now the login system doesn't work. When I type my username and password I'm redirected to index.php again.

Is something wrong with my session code?

Ps.: I already read this question: [How to set and check a session after login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400768/how-to-set-and-check-a-session-after-login) but it didn't work too.

Comment: Using session needed to be start first did you do using `session_start()`.try to `print_R($_SESSION)` to check whether you have set values for session.

Comment: I believe $_SESSION is actually always set, but empty, just as $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. Best to check for !empty($_SESSION) or better yet, assign a key to the particular session variable you want to check such as $_SESSION['logged_in'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to login process i.e is when entered username/password and clicked on submit button.

```
<?php session_start(); 
     /*authenticate the username &^ password*/ 
     if($result) {
         $_SESSION['logged_in']=1; 
     } 
?>
```

now on the admin page

```
<?php session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
           header("location:carro_admin.php");
     } else {
           header("location:index.php");   
     }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Salian... I was adding the session_start in the index.php instead the checklogin.php ... now it's working.

Comment: Salian... it's showing this mesage in my browser when I try to access the admin pages: This webpage has a redirect loop ... do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: don't worry Salian... I fixed it changing the header("location:carro_admin.php"); by session_star();

Answer (score 1):

Do you have session_start () at the top of the page where your redirect is? If not, it won't set the session. I can hit the page from a non-browser, and get all of the contents of your admin page without being redirected. You need to have the script die after the redirect in the case that the user is not logged in. Also, you shouldn't use isset ($_SESSION). You should use something like @$_SESSION["loggedIn"] === TRUE.