# php redirect if already logged in

Tags: php

i am using a simple login form; i want to redirect if an already logged in user comes to login page

Login form

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="uname" required /><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pwd" required /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
  <script>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user']))
            header("Location: booking.php");
          else if(isset($_SESSION['login_status']) && $_SESSION['login_status'] !='') { ?>
    alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['login_status']; ?>');
    <?php  unset($_SESSION['login_status']); session_destroy ();} ?>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP for database connection and query

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
session_start();
$user   =   $_POST['uname'];
$pwd    =   $_POST['pwd'];
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$user = stripslashes($user);
$pwd = stripslashes($pwd);
$pwd    =   sha1($pwd);
$query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname='$user' and pwd='$pwd' and isActive=1";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result=$stmt->fetch();
if($result){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $result['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['login_status'] = "Sucessfully Logged in";
        header("Location: booking.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['login_status'] = "Login Credentials incorrect";
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }
?>
```

This code perfectly works with my localhost but while i put this in a shared hosting if i have already login and goes to the login page it is not redirecting me to page -> booking.php. 
If i give an alret here

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user']))
                header("Location: booking.php");
```

instead of `header("Location: booking.php");` the alert works; but as you can see the very same code works in the php connection page.

Could anyone point out the mistake i have made here?.. 
Please note: Login works without any issue; ie: if i give the correct username and password it redirects me to the corresponding page, only issue is that after logging in if i came back to the login form it's not redirecting me to booking.php page

Comment: Myabe the version on PHP... try coding the complete IF sentence... if(var=1){ ok }else{ header.location}

Comment: Use javascript redirect, see if it works or not, just for debugging. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=booking.php">` or  `window.location.replace("booking.php");`

Comment: Isn't `session_start()` supposed to be in the very first line of your php code?

Comment: @roy I have tried it all; in fact the alert in the very same position executes fine. So i conclude the problem is only with the redirection but the very same code is working fine in another page, that's what confuses me totally

Comment: Have the file the session_start(); and the closing php ?>

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt  Have tried it; no luck.

Comment: @Roy In both the files php tags are properly closed

Comment: @deedee  this might help you
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400768/how-to-set-and-check-a-session-after-login

Comment: @Comirdc  'window.location.replace("booking.php");'  method works

Comment: By the way `header` is for to use before any html code http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt could you please tell the correct method of redirection then?  window.location.replace("booking.php");  causes delay

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt considering your last comment I rewrite the code like this <?php session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user']))
    header("Location: booking.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>   Still no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `header` before html codes. Try something like :

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
   header("Location: booking.php");
   exit();
}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="uname" required /><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pwd" required /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
  <script>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_status']) && $_SESSION['login_status'] !='') { ?>
    alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['login_status']; ?>');
    <?php  unset($_SESSION['login_status']); session_destroy ();} ?>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan.Hunt   :) that solves the issue. In fact i have tried it but i missed exit();     Thanks again for your help   :)

Answer (score 0):

You are unsetting the logging_status and destroying the session in the elseif statement here:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user']))
            header("Location: booking.php");
          else if(isset($_SESSION['login_status']) && $_SESSION['login_status'] !='') { ?>
    alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['login_status']; ?>');
    <?php  unset($_SESSION['login_status']); session_destroy ();} ?>
```

Which is the reason behind failure in redirection and also you have some minor syntax flaws as well `else if -> elseif` and `session_destroy () -> session_destroy()`.

Here is the code that will fix the error for you:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="uname" required /><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pwd" required /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    <script>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&!empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: booking.php");
    }
    elseif(isset($_SESSION['login_status']) && $_SESSION['login_status'] !='')
    {
    ?>
    alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['login_status'];?>');
    <?php
    }
    unset($_SESSION['login_status']);
    session_destroy();
    ?>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```